# Is it possible to make different htaccess user authentication on two different files?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a website made with WordPress and I want to make two different htaccess logins for two template files. Is this possible?

I have this next code for one of the templates but I want to do the same thing for the second template, only with different username and password.

The templates are located in the same directory and the .htaccess, .htpasswd files are in the root of the website.

I tried user username instead of valid-user, made a different directory in public_html for another .htpasswd file with the password and username for the second file. Nothing worked as it should.

The code:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI /colaborators/$ require_auth=true

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /home/my_whole_path/public_html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

Comment: This might probably help -> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_macro.html

Comment: recall: Using htaccess has server performance impact and for a site with hi hit rates, you will drive the bandwidth consumption crazy.  Htaccess requires the server to examine every directory in the path of the current page for any htaccess files in them, read and process before getting to the current page.

Comment: @jobeard, how would this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question, maybe this will help someone:

In my case, I had the .htaccess and .htpasswd files outside WordPress, in the root directory. What I had to do to make my second page .htaccess protected with different user and password than the first one:

I made a new directory in the root folder, inside it I created another .htaccess file and a new .htpasswd, plus my page (called it index.php).

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI /test/$ require_auth=true

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /home/my_whole_path/public_html/new_directory/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

In index.php I loaded WordPress with a require_once 'wp-load.php', the header.php and the rest of the page code.

And that's all.

Hope will help.

Comment: This is basically the answer @Jerodev gave you in your duplicate (now deleted) question http://stackoverflow.com/q/33102058/1741542. So how is this answer different?

Comment: No. It's not the same answer. The difference is that the second page is not a WordPress template anymore. And I didn't make two directories. I made just one for the second page.